# What is the limit of directly detecting a resonance?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, experimental-physics, measurements, resonance

Some resonances are extremely short-lived. With a lifetime of $10^{-23}$ seconds, they would [travel just about the size of the proton ($10^{-15}$ m) even **if** they traveled at the speed of light.$^\dagger$](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~kolena/modern/dudley.html) So apparently with todays technology it is impossible to detect resonances directly, one can only infer their existence from their decay products.

With improved technology, are there any possibilities to detect them directly? If so, what specifically needs to be improved?

What are the limits$^\bullet$ as of today, i.e. how short distances can we measure?

---

- Of course there is a limit, there always is, but it would be nice if some of our more experimentally inclined friends would comment on this.

$\dagger$ Of course, massive particles always travel with speeds less than that of light.

Comment: just a minute, who told you that the emitted particles travel at light speed? Only if it is $\gamma$ ray or neutrinos.

Comment: And next, how do you think that you detect a resonance *"directly"* ? What you mean by directly?

Comment: 1. You missed the point. 2. Direct measurement.

Comment: Remember that the lab-frame travel distance is set by the (dilated) lab-frame lifetime as well as the relative velocity, so your distance estimate is off. This is, of course, the same reason that a large fraction of cosmic-ray muons reach the ground.

Comment: @dmckee I stole that from this site, http://www.phy.duke.edu/~kolena/modern/dudley.html The site looked legit to me.

Comment: Well, they may be making some assumption about the limiting value of $\gamma$, but as the Lorentz factor rises so does the mean lab-frame distance travels even though the lab-frame speed of the particles is not changing appreciably. This only buys a couple of orders of magnitude, but it *does* buy you that.

Comment: My point was not the numbers or estimation but rather I want some experimental girl/dude to come with some insightful comments regarding what is possible or not and why and so on.